# Android studio c++ ndk support

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

One of my friends suggested to use c++ support in Android studio in order to hide passwords. I have found tons of tutorials how to get started with ndk in android. But they are all outdated(2015) and everytime I try to use c++ in any way, Android studio crashes. Is there any way to do it in a simpler way now? 
P.S./ I want to get rid of experimental plugin that every one uses.

Comment: I don't think that Android Studio supports C++ development. I think that you have to use another tool to build your code (such as Eclipse with the NDK) and then link it to the Java code in the Android Studio.

Comment: Android Studio change log: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system  Last mention of NDK was Android Studio 1.3.1 (2015/08/11) .

Answer (score 0):

Little off the question, storing passwords in the native layer does not ensure complete safety. A good hacker can get that as well. It is just that you add another additional layer so one has to dig deeper